# Somethings wrong with GoogleMap SDK iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My app is using both UIkit and cocos2d. After using view with GoogleMap SDK and show cocos scene. xcode show this: 
cocos2d: surface size: 0x0
Failed to make complete framebuffer object 0x8CDD

And the screen is black, and can do nothing except restart app.
I have searched so many website, so many people have same problem but no solution for that.
So is it impossible to use Google Map sdk with cocos2d? If not what can I do?

(Before using GoogleMapsdk I used MKMapview, it doesn't cause this problem but it's not as good as GoogleMap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Maps uses OpenGL ES to render the map.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#requiring_opengl_es_version_2) Two OpenGL renderers can not be mixed, they both use their own GL context. Specifically on iOS there seems to be little support to run two GL views side by side (let alone on top of each other).

So no, for all intents and purposes mixing cocos2d and google maps on iOS is not possible.

Comment: thanks for your help. So sad. Can you give me any sample code with MKMapview?